# Use continue to skip "double iterator" loop in iterated list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm looping through 2D list combined from list1 and list2 with itertools.
I want to check every value if exists from list1 with every value from list2, so it looks like this:

```
if(list1[0] == list2[0])
if(list1[0] == list2[1])
if(list1[0] == list2[3])
if(list1[1] == list2[0])
.
.
.
.
```

If the value is found then continue looping but with list1[+1].

So

```
if list1[0] == list2[3] = True
```

I want to start with `list[1]` again and try it, by skipping the rest of `list1[0]` comparing.

I tried to explain the best, maybe the code will help you understand.

```
import itertools


list1 = ["value1","value2","value3","value4"]
list2 = ["value5","value6","value1","value8"]


mylist = list(itertools.product(list1, list2))


for a,b in mylist:
    if (a == b):
       print ("Found word " + str(a) + " in list2)
       continue
```

So now, after it's found, it needs to continue looping but with a[+1].
However it could work in "classic" loop, but I'm using 2D looping.
Basically, I want to continue with "a" comparing to "b" again.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. Are you in fact trying to find common elements between two lists?

Comment: Sure, either to use them as two lists to compare or by making one list with two of them inside like as in the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in l1:
    l2.remove(x)
```

this will remove all values from l2 that appear in l1

Comment: The values aren't equal. There is a possible value from list1 which may appear in list2. Because lists are so big, I want to check if the value from list1 appear in list2 so I can delete it. I'm doing a comparison.

Comment: so then why don't you loop through l1 and use `.remove()` on l2 for every element in l1. This will leave you with the list of all elements that don't appear in l1. See my updated post

Comment: "Removing" them is a sample, there is much more to explain behind this. Removing them isn't solution